# unable to change the background image of the button in the custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, custom-controls

```
                // Mystock.java

                public class MyStock extends Activity
                {

                    DatabaseHelper db;
                    DownloadFileviaHTTP1 d;
                    private mItems[] itemss;
                    EditText txtPriceEdit=null;
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                    public ListView lst_stockListing;
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps ;
                    ArrayList<mItems> planetList = new ArrayList<mItems>();
                    RelativeLayout slider = null,listview=null,topHeader=null,remaniningBucks=null;
                    Button btn_leftpanel,btn_editstock,btnbuy,btncancel,btnaccept,btnsub,btnadd,btnsell;
                    String[] from = new String[] {"companyName", "ButtonBuy", "currentPrice", "ButtonSell"};
                    private ArrayAdapter<com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.DownloadFileviaHTTP1.mItems> listAdapter;
                    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtstockname_custom, R.id.btnbuy_custom, R.id.txtcurrent_custom, R.id.btnsell_custom };
                    TextView txtnifty=null,txtremainingbucks=null,txt_stockqty=null,txt_quantity=null,txtPrice=null,txtPriceChange=null;

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                    {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.mystock);

                        //Button
                        btn_leftpanel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_leftpanel);
                        btncancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
                        btnaccept=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);
                        btnsub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
                        btnadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
                        btn_editstock=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_editstock);

                        //layout
                        listview=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listview);
                        slider = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_relative_slider);
                        topHeader=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_top_header);
                        remaniningBucks=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_remainingbucks);

                        //TextView
                        txtnifty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnifty50_text);
                        txtremainingbucks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtremainingbucks_text);
                        txt_stockqty=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstockqty);
                        txt_quantity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtquantity);
                        txtPriceEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtprice_edit);
                        txtPrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
                        txtPriceChange=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprice_change);

                        //listview
                        lst_stockListing=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_mystock);

                        itemss = (mItems[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

                        d=new DownloadFileviaHTTP1();

                        txtnifty.setText("100000.00");
                        txtremainingbucks.setText("100000.00");
                        txtremainingbucks.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(105,160,38));

                         ArrayList<Items>details = new ArrayList<Items>();


                            //displyaing the stock in the listview from the table
                            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(MyStock.this,"StockApp");
                            db.getReadableDatabase();
                            Cursor cur=db.view_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK", db);
                            Log.d("cursor count : "," " +cur.getCount());

                         Items item;
                         while(cur.moveToNext())
                         {
                             item=new Items();
                             item.setName(cur.getString(1));
                             item.setPrice(cur.getString(2));
                             Log.d("quantity count ",cur.getString(6));
                             if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(6).toString())>0)
                             {
                                item.setButtonbackground();
                                // btnbuy.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buy_stock_number));
                                 item.setBuy(cur.getString(6));
                             }
                                 details.add(item);
                         } 

                         lst_stockListing.setAdapter(new abc(details , this));


                        function();
                    }
                    public void display_called(Cursor cur)
                    {
                        fillMaps= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                         String s="";
                        int count=0;
                        Log.d("cursor count"," "+cur.getCount());
                        while(cur.moveToNext())
                        { 
                            Log.d("company name",cur.getString(1));
                           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                           String str=cur.getString(1);
                           s="";
                           count=0;
                           for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                           {    
                            char c=str.charAt(i);
                            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)==true)
                            {
                                count=count+1;
                                if (count==2)
                                    s=s+System.getProperty("line.separator");
                                else
                                    s=s+c;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                s=s+c;
                            }
                           }
                           map.put("companyName",s);
                           map.put("ButtonBuy"," " );
                           map.put("currentPrice",cur.getString(2));
                           map.put("ButtonSell"," ");
                           fillMaps.add(map);
                       }
                    }
                    public static class Items
                    {
                        private String companyName = "";
                        private Button btnbuy=null;
                        private String price = "";
                        private String buy,sell;

                        public Items() 
                        {

                        }
                        public Items(String name)
                        {
                            this.companyName = name;    
                        }
                        public Items(String name,String price)
                        {
                            this.companyName=name;
                            this.price=price;
                        }
                        public Items(String name,String price,String buy,String sell)
                        {
                            this.companyName=name;
                            this.price=price;
                            this.buy=buy;
                            this.sell=sell;
                        }
                        public void setButtonbackground()
                        {
                            btnbuy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buy_stock_number);
                        }
                        public String getName() 
                        {
                            return companyName;
                        }

                        public String getPrice()
                        {
                            return price;
                        }
                        public String getBuy()
                        {
                            return buy;
                        }
                        public String getSell()
                        {
                            return sell;
                        }

                        public void setName(String name) 
                        {
                            this.companyName = name;
                        }
                        public void setPrice(String price)
                        {
                            this.price=price;
                        }
                        public void setBuy(String buy)
                        {
                            this.buy=buy;
                        }
                        public void setSell(String sell)
                        {
                            this.sell=sell;
                        }
                    }

                    public class abc extends BaseAdapter
                    {

                        private ArrayList<Items> _data;
                        Context _c;

                         abc (ArrayList<Items> data, Context c)
                         {
                                _data = data;
                                _c = c;
                         }
                        public int getCount() 
                        {
                             return _data.size();
                        }

                        public Object getItem(int position) 
                        {   
                            return _data.get(position);
                        }

                        public long getItemId(int position) 
                        {   
                            return position;
                        }

                        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                        {
                             final Items item =new Items();

                            View v = convertView;
                             if (v == null)
                             {
                                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_mystock, null);
                             }

                               TextView companyName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtstockname_custom);
                               Button buy = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnbuy_custom);
                               TextView current= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtcurrent_custom);
                               Button sell = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnsell_custom);


                               Items msg = _data.get(position);
                               Log.d("msg view paret ",""+msg);

                               companyName.setText(msg.companyName);
                               current.setText(msg.price);
                               buy.setText(msg.buy) ;
                               sell.setText(msg.sell);

                               buy.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v1)
                                   {
                                       slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                       /* Items i =lst_stockListing.getChildCount();
                                        holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());
                                        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());*/
                                       DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(MyStock.this,"StockApp");
                                        db.getReadableDatabase();
                                        Cursor cur=db.view_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK", db);
                                        Log.d("cursor count : "," " +cur.getCount());
                                        db.close();
                                        cur.move(position);
                                        while(cur.moveToNext())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(MyStock.this,cur.getString(2), 1000).show();
                                            txtPrice.setText(cur.getString(2));
                                            txtPriceEdit.setText(cur.getString(2));
                                            Float i=Float.parseFloat(txtPrice.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(txt_quantity.getText().toString());
                                            txtPriceChange.setText(""+i);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                   }
                               });
                               sell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) 
                                   {
                                       slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                       txtPrice.setText(""+position);
                                        Toast.makeText(MyStock.this," "+position, 1000).show();     
                                   }
                               });
                               return v;
                        }
                    }
                    public class periodicChecker extends Thread
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            while(true)
                            {
                                 try 
                                   {
                                       final Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                    refresh.post(new Runnable() 
                                    {

                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                                planetList.clear();
                                                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyStock.this, "", "Fetching Current Price...");
                                                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(MyStock.this,"StockApp");
                                                db.getWritableDatabase();
                                                Cursor cur=db.view_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK", db);
                                                Log.d("cursor count : "," " +cur.getCount());
                                                db.close();
                                                display_called(cur);
                                                while(cur.moveToNext())
                                                    Log.d("cursor symbol",cur.getString(0));
                                                d.downloadFileViaHTTP1(db);
                                                //listAdapter = new com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.DownloadFileviaHTTP1.SelectArralAdapter(MyStock.this,planetList);
                                                //lst_stockListing.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Thread.sleep(50000);

                                    } 
                                   catch (InterruptedException e) 
                                   {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    void function()
                    {
                        btn_leftpanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {   
                                Intent in =new Intent(MyStock.this,ListingItem.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        });

                        btn_editstock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {   
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {   

                                Log.d("top position ","" +listview.getTop());
                            }
                        });
                        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {
                                Log.d("cancel","called");
                                slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        btnaccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {   
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {               

                            }
                        });
                        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                int val=Integer.parseInt(txt_stockqty.getText().toString());
                                if (val<100)
                                    val=val+10;

                                txt_stockqty.setText(""+val);
                                txt_quantity.setText(""+val);
                                txtPriceEdit.setText(""+txtPrice.getText().toString());
                                float val1=Float.parseFloat(txtPriceEdit.getText().toString());             
                                txtPriceChange.setText("" + val*val1);
                            }
                        });
                        btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {   
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                int val=Integer.parseInt(txt_stockqty.getText().toString());
                                if (val>10)
                                    val=val-10;

                                txt_stockqty.setText(""+val);
                                txt_quantity.setText(""+val);
                                txtPriceEdit.setText(txtPrice.getText().toString());
                                float val1=Float.parseFloat(txtPriceEdit.getText().toString());
                                txtPriceChange. setText(""+val*val1);
                            }
                        });
                        txtPriceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            //===========
            //mystock.xml
            //=============
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_name"
                    android:layout_width="320dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/layout_remainingbucks"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_header2" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtstockname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/lblstockname"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtbuy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtcurrent"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/lblbuy"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtcurrent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtsell"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/lblcurrent"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtsell"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/lblsell"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            //==================
            //custom_mystock.xml
           //===================
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtstockname_custom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnbuy_custom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/lblstockname"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnbuy_custom"
                    android:layout_width="53dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtcurrent_custom"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buy_stock2"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtcurrent_custom"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnsell_custom"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/lblcurrent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnsell_custom"
                    android:layout_width="52dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seperator_header2"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="@drawable/sell_stock2"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
//========
//logcat
//======
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/cursor(28082):  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40564dd0
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/cursor count :(28082):  5
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/quantity count(28082): 0
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/quantity count(28082): 0
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/quantity count(28082): 0
04-11 18:12:17.110: D/quantity count(28082): 10
04-11 18:12:17.110: W/dalvikvm(28082): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indusa.stockapp/com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.MyStock}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 18:12:17.130: E/AndroidRuntime(28082):    at com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.MyStock.onCreate(MyStock.java:110)

//======
//note 
//=====
```

//in the above code my listview is dispalyed with textbox,button,textbox and button if at //the load time in the data base if there is quantity purchased of any quantity then i want //to change the R.drawable .buy_stock2 to R.drawable.buy_stock_number of that specific //button i m unable to differetiate the  buttons based on their id ..

Comment: post your logcat output also

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `buttons` you can use the good facility provided by android `imagebutton` with it is easy to handle the look and feel of that control...

Comment: first of all my main aim is to change the background of the button if the quantity of the particular stock is bought by the user other wise buy stock image should be displayed ...i m getting the null pointer exception because stocks displyed having the button ids as same

Comment: thats what i am saying use the imagebutton instead of button...it works similarly as the button...

Comment: it doesnt make sense whehter i use button or image button both of them works same

Comment: changing the button background is also easy not much difficult

Comment: update your question with your logcat trace so that all can see where are you getting error

Answer (score 0):

You are using ListView and it doesn't create a new view for each item, it reuses cached views, so if you want to change some property in list items you should do that in adapter method

```
getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and you can identify there your item by position argument.
After changing listview data you should call method Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() that method notify list view to redraw its items and now your getView logic works